# Permission Denied on Folder on separate partition - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, user-groups

I have a user : hduser. Both that user and myself (bearrito) are in a group called : datumsuser

I have executed the following commands:

```
 sudo  chgrp -R datumsuser /media/bearrito/
 sudo  chmod -R 770 /media/bearrito
```

Resulting in the following:

```
media # ls -lah
total 20K 
drwxrwxr-x   5 root     root       4.0K May 13 19:47 .
drwxr-xr-x  24 root     root       4.0K Jul 14 21:53 ..
drwxrws---+  2 bearrito datumsuser 4.0K Jul 14 22:09 bearrito
drwxrwxrwx   2 root     root       4.0K May 13 19:47 MyAndroid
drwxr-x---+  2 root     root       4.0K May 21 15:55 temp
```

However,as hduser when I execute:

```
cd /media/bearrito/
bash: cd: /media/bearrito/: Permission denied
```

I simply want the hduser to be able to read and write to either that top-level directory or a sub-directory.

Is this an fstab issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is not an fstab issue.   It could be an issue with /media not having appropriate perms, or possibly (but less likely) something to do with Apparmour (or conceivably SELinux).  Try modifying the perms on /media to bearrito can read it.